# How to make a xna leaderboard?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone

I've got a simple Game for windows phone where the player drags a ship around the screen to collect items and avoid asteroids. Every time an item is collected, a score counter at the top of the screen increases by one.

The thing is, I'd like to have the game transition into a leaderboard once the player's ship collides with a asteroid, and I can't figure out how I would go about it.

I have an integer that stores the score value, but once the player collides with an asteroid, the value of that integer of reset (of course).

How can I go about storing what the final value of the player's score before death to a separate integer and the display it on the leaderboard screen? No need to explain gamestate management, I already know how to play around with that.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you mean "leaderboard" you mean a local one, one connected to your own webservice, or a third party one?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to keep everything regarding this app offline.

Answer (score 2):

First off, in your code that handles what happens when an asteroid collides, you will need first save your score, and then after this is completed, reset it. When you display it, you will need to load your leaderboard from a serialized file.

I'm not going to go into detail, because I found a site that basicly explains what I would tell you: http://xnaessentials.com/tutorials/highscores.aspx

Ofcourse you will need to modify this a little and add a way to order high scores, but I suspect this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.Before you can reset the variable score to 0 when a collision is detected, store the score in the isolated storage settings with the key as profile name. You can make additional things like store only if the already present key value is lesser or storing it straight away if no key value found.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method of retaining the high score after the game ends is to make the int static and only reset it to zero at the start of a new game - rather than when the game ends.

So in your MyGame class:
internal static int Score = 0;

In whatever function starts a new game:
MyGame.Score = 0;

and in your Leaderboard screen:
List highScores = new List();

...

if (highScores.Count == 0 || MyGame.Score > highScores[highScores.Count-1]) {
  // the score made the ordered list Leaderboard (you'll need to limit it to some maxiumum number of scores)
}